# AJAX - What content type should have JSON encoded data?

Tags: php, html, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The *right* JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)

Hi

If I send some stuff in a ajax request with `json_encode(...)` what "Content-type" should I set with `header()` ? Same like HTML?  (text/html)

And does this setting affect the site in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See 
[What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)

The correct content-type is:
application/json